# Theorem environment with hanging indentation

Tags: indentation, theorems

I would like to define a theorem environment with custom layout. In particular, I want the body of the theorem to be indented, like this

```
Text body. Text body. Text body.

Theorem 1 (Pythagoras).
    Let a,b,c the sides of a rectangular triangle.
    Without loss of generality, we assume that  a<b<c .
    Then, the following equality holds:
           a^2 + b^2 = c^2

More text. And even more text.
```

This is similar to the `quote` environment, I believe.

How can I do this?

Preferably, I would like to use the existing `\newtheorem` command, but that's not mandatory.

Comment: @Dilaton Oh, thanks, sounds cool. I'll join up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you would like to use the standard LaTeX theorem commands, here's a solution for that: let's insert `\newline\quote` into the beginning of a theorem and `\endquote` at the end. A complete compilable example for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\trivlist
   \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2}]\mbox\newline\quote\itshape}
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
      \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2\ (#3)}]\mbox\newline\quote\itshape}
\def\@endtheorem{\endquote\endtrivlist}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\section*{The Theorem of Pythagoras}
Text body. Text body. Text body.
\begin{thm}[Pythagoras]
    Let $a,b,c$ the sides of a rectangular triangle.
    Without loss of generality, we assume that  $a<b<c$ .
    Then, the following equality holds:
          \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{thm}
More text. And even more text.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

That's a point to start for you. You may insert additional commands of your own regarding spacing and formatting. For instance you may notice that I used `\mbox` before `\newline` to get a line break - if I write `\mbox{}` instead there would be more space, if I omit it there cannot be a line break at this point (or use `\leavevmode`). Simply writing `\par` instead of `\newline` would not work.

You may also consider to use one of these useful theorem packages:

- [amsthm](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)
- [ntheorem](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem)

Both offer commands for customizing theorem layouts.

Comment: A variation on the theme:

    \usepackage{thmtools}
    \addtotheorempostheadhook{\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\par\smallskip\quote}
    \addtotheoremprefoothook{\endquote}
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

(Bleepin' bloop, this one could do with a formatter as well...)

Comment: I checked amsthm and ntheorem, neither have easy access to what the OP wanted. ntheorem offers a way to indent the entire theorem, includeing the theorem heading, and also a way to insert a line break between the theorem heading and theorem text, but I couldn't see a way to "unindent" the theorem heading there.

Comment: In that case theorem environments of those packages could be patched in a similar way, inserting a quote environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm! Sometimes, however, LaTeX feels entitled to insert a page break after the `\newline`. Is there any way to prevent that? Hopefully, this will only be a minor issue, though.

Comment: @Greg: to avoid such bad page breaks I like to use the `needspace` package: http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace

Comment: There seems to be a glitch with the amsthm package. Not sure why?

Answer (score 9):

I just did it like this (with `amsthm`):

`\newtheoremstyle{indenteddefinition}{\topsep}{\topsep}{\hangindent=2em}{}{}{}{.5em}{}`

this works only for one paragraph though. better:

`\newtheoremstyle{indenteddefinition}{.5\topsep}{.5\topsep}{\addtolength{\leftskip}{2.5em}}{-2.5em}{}{}{ }{}`

i realized though that this doesnt nest.

Comment: Thanks, this is a million times better than the @-heavy solution that got accepted! I was actually going to ask how to do it with the `amsthm` package when I found your answer. I'm glad I did :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work well with lists inside it.

Answer (score 6):

I've used [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) for my answer. You might want to look at page 7 (predefined theorem styles) of the manual.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % needed for math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremindent20pt 
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
Text body. Text body. Text body.

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
    Let $a,b,c$ the sides of a rectangular triangle.
    Without loss of generality, we assume that  $a<b<c$.

    Then, the following equality holds:
           \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{theorem}

More text. And even more text.
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]