# Theorem environment - line break after label

Tags: line-breaking, amsmath, theorems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ntheorem environment with indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/ntheorem-environment-with-indentation)
>   [Skipping line after “Proof” in proof environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36851/skipping-line-after-proof-in-proof-environment)

```
\begin{theorem}[label]
The theorem text.
\end{theorem}
```

I want to have automatically a line break after the label. So far I always do the following

```
\begin{theorem}[label]\ \\
The theorem text.
\end{theorem}
```

I thought of renewing the theorem environment. But I would need to do this several times since I've got a few theorem environments (lemma, proposition, corollar, etc.) and I always want a line break after the label.

Comment: It really depends on your loaded package. Please have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/is-it-possible-to-skip-the-first-line-in-a-theorem-environment

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer depends on the package used to declare the theorem-like structures. If you are using the `ntheorem` package, you can simply use the predefined `break` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some note]
\lipsum*[2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using `amsthm`, you will have to define your own style through the `\newtheoremstyle` command. Here's an example of such a definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some note]
\lipsum*[2]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do this method and it works for most cases except when I begin `\begin{enumerate}` right after the theorem. in whcih case it dosnt break

Comment: I have just encountered the same problem with `\begin{enumerate}`. Would be happy for help, or I'll try a different package probably.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. I need to further produce a little indent. (After the heading of the theorem, I need to have a new paragraph.) How can I do this?

Comment: I found a hack for the itemize/enumerate situation - just add an empty item as the first one

Comment: Did anyone find solution for `\begin{enumerate}` situation?

Comment: @Travis Adam's solution/hack works well: just add `\item[]` (empty item with an empty label) as your first item. You can also simply start your theorem with `\hfill`, this works regardless whether you're starting with a list or not.

Answer (score 30):

this is a "break" style recommended in the ams' "newtheorem and theoremstyle test" for `amsthm`:

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}% name
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

look here for the [pdf output](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/thmtest.pdf) and the [input](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/thmtest.tex) for this documentation.  the files (named `thmtest.*`) are also on ctan.

Comment: What if I want theorems to be on a new line but propositions on the same line? like `theorem 12\\Let $x$ be...` but `proposition 23: For all $y$...`

Comment: @metacompactness -- use a different `\theoremstyle`.  `\theoremstyle{plain}` is the most appropriate for propositions.  (`amsthm` has three predefined styles; they are described in the documentation.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. (I was looking for a solution and I found it here!) But my problem is further complicated. I have a definition (with `amsthm`) and after the heading of the definition I have like two paragraphs but when I applied your solution I get no indent for the first paragraph. The only way I can fix this is by removing the indent with `\noindent` of the second paragraph. Can I, instead, make the first paragraph with an indent? Thanks.

Comment: @Riebuoz -- what you're asking is really a new question.  please post one, providing a small, compilable example that demonstrates the result you're getting, and a description of how what you want differs.  the compilable example means that people here can easily cut and paste the code, making it very easy to experiment.  that's the best way to get an answer quickly.  you can include a pointer to this question and say how it's relevant.