# A theoremstyle with complete indentation using amsthm

Tags: indentation, theorems, amsthm

I want to define a theoremstyle using amsthm, such that the complete environments content produced by `\newtheorem` with this style are indented.

The following standalone example uses an adapted version of a suggestion posted in [theorem-environment-with-hanging-indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5526/theorem-environment-with-hanging-indentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheoremstyle{indented}{3pt}{3pt}{\addtolength{\leftskip}{2.5em}}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{}

\theoremstyle{indented}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext
  \begin{definition}[test]
    some text
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item an item
      \item another item
    \end{enumerate}
    more text.
  \end{definition}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

which will produce a result like this:
[image: result]

The question at hand is of course, how can an indentation be realized, such that lists will be indented too. Would it for instance be advisable, to format the whole environment as a list? If so, how?

I would prefer to keep the definition as simple as possible, without for instance redefining amsthm commands.

Comment: works perfectly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code can be made to work by modifying both `\@totalleftmargin` (which controls nested list indentation) and `\linewidth` as well as issuing a `\parshape` to take these changes into consideration:

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\Blabla}{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{indented}
  {3pt}% space before
  {3pt}% space after
  {\addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{3.5em}
   \addtolength{\linewidth}{-3.5em}
   \parshape 1 3.5em \linewidth}% body font
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% header font
  {.}% punctuation
  {.5em}% after theorem header
  {}% header specification (empty for default)
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{indented}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\Blabla
\begin{definition}
\Blabla
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \Blabla
  \item \Blabla
\end{enumerate}
\Blabla
\[A=B\]
\Blabla
\end{definition}
\Blabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach does not affect the equation environment. This may be problematic if you also want to increase the indentation of equations with the `fleqn` option in the book class for instance.

Comment: `\addtolength{\mathindent}{2.5em}` shall also be added then

Comment: @pluton: thanks for spotting this. A better solution is to use `\parshape 1 3.5em \linewidth` which will work correctly whether or not the `fleqn` option is used. This will also take care of the problem mentioned in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116379.

Answer (score 13):

I think that *all* theorem-like environments should be treated in the same way, so a solution can be to use `list` instead of `trivlist` in the definitions, thus making it possible to use `\leftmargin`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\trivlist}{\list{}{\leftmargin=2.5em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Now statements such as

```
\newtheoremstyle{indentedupright}
  {3pt}
  {3pt}
  {} 
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {}
```

for definitions and

```
\newtheoremstyle{indenteditalic}
  {3pt}
  {3pt}
  {\itshape} 
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {}
```

for theorems will do.

---

Here's an extended version that allows to have different indentations for the various theorem-like environments:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\trivlist}{\list{}{\leftmargin=\thm@margin}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
\newlength{\thm@margin}
\newcommand{\xnewtheorem}[2][0pt]{%
  \newenvironment{#2}{\thm@margin=#1 \begin{#2INNER}}{\end{#2INNER}}%
  \newtheorem{#2INNER}%
}

\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{indentedupright}
  {3pt}
  {3pt}
  {} 
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {}
\newtheoremstyle{indenteditalic}
  {3pt}
  {3pt}
  {\itshape} 
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {}

\theoremstyle{indenteditalic}
\xnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{indentedupright}
\xnewtheorem[2.5em]{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{definition}[Companion and cut-off event]
\label{def:cutoff}
Let $\beta$ be a branching process and let $\prec$ be an adequate partial order on the 
configurations of $\beta$. An event $e$ is a \emph{cut-off event} (with respect to $\prec$) 
if $\beta$ contains a local configuration $[e']$ such that
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Mark(e) = Mark(e')$, and \label{def:cutoff-markequal}
\item $[e'] \prec [e]$ \label{def:cutoff-smaller}
\end{enumerate}
Another way to express the condition \ref{def:cutoff-markequal} is $e' \in [e]_{Mark}$. The 
event $e'$ is called \emph{companion} of $e$, if in addition it is minimal in $[e]_{Mark}$ 
with respect to $\prec$. Moreover, if $\prec$ is total, then the companion of a cut-off 
event $e$ is uniquely defined and is denoted by $e_{\mathfrak{c}}$.
\end{definition}
\blindtext
\begin{theorem}
This is the statement of an important theorem; however we don't want to have an indentation 
for this kind of statement.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Note that if a new theorem must share a counter with another, the syntax should be like

```
\xnewtheorem{prop}[theoremINNER]{Proposition}
```

(with or without the optional argument for the indentation).

---

A variant for specifying both the left and the right margin; in this case the lengths are mandatory arguments; it would be possible to add a key-value interface instead.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}
  {\trivlist}
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=\thm@leftmargin\rightmargin=\thm@rightmargin}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}
  {\endtrivlist}
  {\endlist}
  {}{}
\newlength{\thm@leftmargin}
\newlength{\thm@rightmargin}

\newcommand{\xnewtheorem}[3]{%
  \newenvironment{#3}
    {\thm@leftmargin=#1\relax\thm@rightmargin=#2\relax\begin{#3INNER}}
    {\end{#3INNER}}%
  \newtheorem{#3INNER}%
}

\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{indentedupright}
  {3pt}
  {3pt}
  {} 
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {}
\newtheoremstyle{indenteditalic}
  {3pt}
  {3pt}
  {\itshape} 
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {}

\theoremstyle{indenteditalic}
\xnewtheorem{0pt}{0pt}{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{indentedupright}
\xnewtheorem{2.5em}{0pt}{definition}{Definition}
\xnewtheorem{2.5em}{2.5em}{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{definition}[Companion and cut-off event]\label{def:cutoff}
Let $\beta$ be a branching process and let $\prec$ be an adequate partial order on the 
configurations of $\beta$. An event $e$ is a \emph{cut-off event} (with respect to $\prec$) 
if $\beta$ contains a local configuration $[e']$ such that
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Mark(e) = Mark(e')$, and \label{def:cutoff-markequal}
\item $[e'] \prec [e]$ \label{def:cutoff-smaller}
\end{enumerate}
Another way to express the condition \ref{def:cutoff-markequal} is $e' \in [e]_{Mark}$. The 
event $e'$ is called \emph{companion} of $e$, if in addition it is minimal in $[e]_{Mark}$ 
with respect to $\prec$. Moreover, if $\prec$ is total, then the companion of a cut-off 
event $e$ is uniquely defined and is denoted by $e_{\mathfrak{c}}$.
\end{definition}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{theorem}
This is the statement of an important theorem; however we don't want to have an indentation 
for this kind of statement.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{example}
\lipsum[4]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is possible add right margin like adjustwidth environment from changepage package?

Comment: @juanquispe Just add `\rightmargin=<length>` next to the setting of `\leftmargin=\thm@margin`

Comment: thanks, but whit this can I obtain a dynamic option like left margin?

Comment: @juanquispe I'll add a modified version.

Comment: why the fonts in your response looks different that in other response?

Comment: @juanuni I see no difference: perhaps it's just an effect of the resolution with which the images have been saved.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the [`changepage`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/changepage/changepage.pdf) package with `adjustwidth` option as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newtheoremstyle{indented}{3pt}{3pt}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{}
%
\theoremstyle{indented}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext
  \begin{adjustwidth}{20pt}{20pt}
  \begin{definition}[test]
    some text
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item an item
      \item another item
    \end{enumerate}
    more text.
  \end{definition}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the above can be made into a `\newcommand` or a `\newenvironment` as you please.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it introduces a spurious white line before the definition.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet is possible remove that spurious white line?

Comment: @juanquispe: you can add `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` just before `\begin{definition}`.