# Line break in list in indented theorem

Tags: indentation, theorems, amsthm

I'm trying to make an indented theorem environment as in [A theoremstyle with complete indentation using amsthm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67242/a-theoremstyle-with-complete-indentation-using-amsthm/67308).

Here's a minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
  \newtheoremstyle{indent}
  {3pt}% space before
  {3pt}% space after
  {
    \setlength{\leftskip}{2.5em}
    \setlength{\rightskip}{2.5em}
    \addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{2.5em}
  }% body font
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% header font
  {.}% punctuation
  {.5em}% after theorem header
  {}% header specification (empty for default)
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{indent}\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}[correct spacing]
\blindtext
\begin{itemize}
\item This is ok.
\item \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Whether or not I add that extra rightskip, my problem is that as soon as an item in a list within my theorem gets longer than one line (as in the third blindtext) it extends over the original right margin of the page, a case not considered in the original post.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a slightly different approach, along the lines of the second and third answers in [A theoremstyle with complete indentation using amsthm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67242/a-theoremstyle-with-complete-indentation-using-amsthm).

Using the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) and the [`changepage`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/changepage) package as follows

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{2.5em}}
\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{\end{adjustwidth}}
```

we get

[image: screenshot]

which I think is the desired result.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

  \newtheoremstyle{indent}
  {3pt}% space before
  {3pt}% space after
  { }% body font
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% header font
  {.}% punctuation
  {.5em}% after theorem header
  {}% header specification (empty for default)
\theoremstyle{indent}\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5em}{2.5em}}
\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{\end{adjustwidth}}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}[correct spacing]
\blindtext
\begin{itemize}
\item This is ok.
\item \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works - ubuntu users like me also have to install the latest `etoolbox`, since the one included in texlive-full doesn't support `\AtBeginEnvironment` yet it seems (1.8 -> 2.1).

Comment: @Bristol great! make sure you're not using an old version from the repositories- have a look here: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: This solution seems to annihilate the effect of the second argument, that the "space after" the environment. It should probably be reincorporated in the `\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{}` instruction? And it also affects the "space before" I believe...