# Theorem style with margin on both sides

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I'm strugeling with the theorem package `thmtools` and its features.
I've declared several theorem styles with `\declaretheoremstyle` and `\declaretheorem`.

How can I add a hanging paragraph margin on the left relative to the length of the theorem type and an absoulte margin on the right? As shown in the picture, the first line containing the theorem header, should be indented as in the rest of the document. The acctual content of the theorem however,  should have a margin on the left as wide as the theorem type "Example". The margin on the right should be defined by an absoulte value. While I have found solutions on indenting the left margin (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106572/indent-theorem-like-hangindent-but-for-multiple-paragraphs)), I have not found anything on doing so with the exact length of the theorem type and nothing on an absoulte margin on the right.

[image: illustration of (1)]

A minimal example of the theorem style above in action:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=\topsep, 
    spacebelow=\topsep,
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\normalfont, 
    notebraces={$\lbrack$}{$\rbrack$},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    postheadspace=\newline
]{examplebreak}

\declaretheorem[style=examplebreak,name=Example]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[First Example]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: You can review the egreg response in this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67242/a-theoremstyle-with-complete-indentation-using-amsthm/67332?noredirect=1#comment567780_67332

Comment: Thanls, but this does not contain a way for the theorem title / text to be "hanging".

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\declaretheoremstyle[
% spaceabove=\topsep,
% spacebelow=\topsep,
% headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
% notefont=\normalfont\mdseries,
%% notebraces={$\lbrack$}{$\rbrack$},
% bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
% % postheadspace=\newline
%]{examplebreak}

\newlength\exampleindent
\settowidth{\exampleindent}{\bfseries Example}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{examplebreak}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          \llap{##1}\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut\vspace{1pt}}}}]}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          \llap{##1}\ ##2\ \normalfont\mdseries[##3]\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut\vspace{1pt}}}}]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{examplebreak}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theoremindent\exampleindent
\theoremrightindent 1.5cm
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[First Example]
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{example}

\begin{example}%[First Example]
    \lipsum[4]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good! But would it be totally irrational of me if I wanted to stick with the thmtools package? I have declared roundabout 10 theorems and I'll probably run into some different looking styles whed using `nthoerem`. Will I not?

Comment: `thmtools` can use `ntheorem` as a backend, with some restrictions. Also, probably most of what you set with thmtools can be set with ntheorem. Ntheorem default layout, as far as I know, is LaTeX default and its normal use is to modify LaTeX default from scratch.

Comment: Okay. How would I do that and does it mean I can use `thmtools` and `ntheorem` concurrently? Because as of now if I add `\usepackage{ntheorem}` to my preample all `\declaretheoremstyle` created theorems produce errors. So I guess I would have to convert them all to the `ntheroem` syntax?!

Comment: Probably some of the keys are not recognized by `ntheorem`. That was the problem in your post: the `notefont`  key is not known to ntheorem, hence I had to patch the closest ntheorem style (which is `plainbreak`) and insert the necessary commands to realise what you want.Very useful, ntheorem defines the `theoremindent`  and `\theoremrightindent` lengths/commands. Note one of the strengths of `ntheorem` is its automatic placement of the `end-of-proof ` symbols.

Comment: Having converted all `thmtools` int `ntheorem` definitions I must say I'm not cinviced, or maybe I just don't get it. ;) E.g. once I have added `\theoremindent` to one of the definitions, all other theorems also have the same ident no matter if the tag is used in that definition. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The system of declarations  remains valid  until the group is ended, or until you set another value. So either you add a pair `{…}`  or you set again `\theoremindent 0pt \theoremrightindent 0pt`. I hope I am clear.