# Loosing top/bottom theorem spacing when using adjustwidth

Tags: lists, indentation, amsthm

In attempting to match a convention used in my math book, I would like to have theorems, lemmas, definitions, et al., indented from both left/right margins. Wrapping the theorem with "\begin{adjustwidth}{.6cm}{.6cm}" results in different top/bottom spacing between text. I can correct this with calls to /vspace but this seems a bit kludgy. Is there is better approach to formatting or am I stuck with calls to \vspace?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amstext}
\usepackage{changepage}

% Redefine theorem style
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
    {\topsep}                    % Space above
    {\topsep}                    % Space below
    {\itshape}                   % Body font
    {\parindent}                 % Indent amount
    {\bfseries}                  % Theorem head font
    {.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
    {0.5em}                      % Space after theorem head
    {}                           % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{theorem}
   This theorem looks correct, but I haven't applied any indentation. 
   It follows the indentation of the document.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{adjustwidth}{.6cm}{.6cm}
\begin{theorem}
   This theorem has had indentation applied and the result is different
   spacing above and below it.
\end{theorem}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the issue arose also in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67332/4686 and its comments, which is one of the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67242/a-theoremstyle-with-complete-indentation-using-amsthm. Another answer to the same question is mentioned in egreg's answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose not using `adjustwidth`, but a small modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67251/4427

The trick with `\normalparindent` is necessary in order to avoid timing problem (in a `\list` the `\parindent` parameter is set to zero).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amstext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}
  {\trivlist}
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=\thm@leftmargin\rightmargin=\thm@rightmargin}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}
  {\endtrivlist}
  {\endlist}
  {}{}
\newlength{\thm@leftmargin}
\newlength{\thm@rightmargin}

\newcommand{\xnewtheorem}[3]{%
  \newenvironment{#3}
    {\thm@leftmargin=#1\relax\thm@rightmargin=#2\relax\begin{#3INNER}}
    {\end{#3INNER}}%
  \newtheorem{#3INNER}%
}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\setlength{\normalparindent}{1sp}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\makeatother

% Redefine theorem style
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
    {\topsep}                    % Space above
    {\topsep}                    % Space below
    {\itshape}                   % Body font
    {\normalparindent}           % Indent amount
    {\bfseries}                  % Theorem head font
    {.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
    {0.5em}                      % Space after theorem head
    {}                           % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\xnewtheorem{.6cm}{.6cm}{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{theorem}
   This theorem looks correct, but I haven't applied any indentation. 
   It follows the indentation of the document.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{theorem}
   This theorem has had indentation applied and the result is different
   spacing above and below it.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic problem with `theorem` environment (*the one as redefined by `amsthm`*) being used as the first thing following an `\item`. (there is an hidden `\item` from the `adjustwidth` environment). This goes a bit deep into LaTeX's management of lists.

Rather than patching `theorem`, I propose here a hack on `adjustwidth`, which may be enough for your document, but may have aftereffects I have not tried to discover. Done with `etoolbox`'s `\apptocmd`, for commodity.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amstext}
\usepackage{changepage}

% Redefine theorem style

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
    {\topsep}   % Space above
    {\topsep}   % Space below
    {\itshape}                   % Body font
    {\parindent}                 % Indent amount
    {\bfseries}                  % Theorem head font
    {.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
    {0.5em}                      % Space after theorem head
    {}                           % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] 

% HACKING \adjustwidth
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\adjustwidth{\@inlabelfalse\@newlistfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{theorem}
   This theorem looks correct, but I haven't applied any indentation. 
   It follows the indentation of the document.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{adjustwidth}{.6cm}{.6cm}
\begin{theorem}
   This theorem has had indentation applied and the result is with similar
   spacing above and below it as in previous theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

---

### Update

I have looked a little deeper in the matter, and it appears that this "feature" (misbehavior?) of the `theorem` environment from package `amsthm` can be explained by the fact that  `amsthm` uses `\trivlist` but does not use a standard `\item` (or rather `\@item`). A macro `\deferred@thm@head` takes its place and is lacking some conditional test that is done by the regular `\@item`: there is no `\if@noparitem \@donoparitem \else  ...` part.

Here is the original:

```
\def\deferred@thm@head#1{%
  \if@inlabel \indent \par \fi % eject a section head if one is pending
  \if@nobreak
    \adjust@parskip@nobreak
  \else
    \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
    \addvspace\@topsep
    \addvspace{-\parskip}%
  \fi
  \global\@inlabeltrue
  \everypar\dth@everypar
  \sbox\@labels{\normalfont#1}%
  \ignorespaces
}
```

Redefining it to be, on the model of the LaTeX kernel `\@item` :

```
\def\deferred@thm@head#1{%
\if@noparitem
  \@noparitemfalse
\else
  \if@inlabel \indent \par \fi % eject a section head if one is pending
  \if@nobreak
    \adjust@parskip@nobreak
  \else
    \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
    \addvspace\@topsep
    \addvspace{-\parskip}%
  \fi
  \global\@inlabeltrue
\fi
  \everypar\dth@everypar
  \sbox\@labels{\normalfont#1}%
  \ignorespaces
}
```

I observe that with the patched macro there will be no extra blank line if the `theorem` environment is used as the very first thing in an `\item`. The patch effect actually even suppresses the default vertical spaces added by `theorem`,  all vertical space responsability falls upon the shoulders of the surrounding list, if there is one (in the case of `adjustwidth`, that means basically no extra vertical space). Thus this is only a proposal, but it allows to delegate entirely to the surrounding list environment the setting for vertical spacing. And we can then control via the list environment the left and right margin, etc...

As no extra blank line arises from a standard `theorem` environment following an `\item` in a list, this feature of `amsthm` appears to be a mis-behavior.