# Conflict between hyperref and etoolbox packages

Tags: hyperref, packages, incompatibility, etoolbox

I'm trying to compile a file using `hyperref` to get hyperlinks and `etoolbox`, for I want a specific setup for theorems that I actually found here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424034/248426). However, just the mere mention of `etoolbox` makes my LaTeX crash!

Here's a MWE with error and the log file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
If you can read this, then it works.
\end{document}
```

This is what I get on terminal (I compile from gedit directly into bash), using Ubuntu xenial and texlive from the Debian repositories (if that's somehow helpful).

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\AfterEndDocument ->\AddToHook 
                               {enddocument/end}

l.6 \begin{document}
```

I have literally no idea how to fix this or why this happens. I'd really like to keep both `etoolbox` and `hyperref` since when using one without the other, I get exactly what I want (provided of course, getting no features of the missing package).

Thanks for reading me!

**EDIT**

The LOG file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B64UwilPqReEByvE51H_tX4tj3N21qQC/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show the compplete log file for your given MWE?

Comment: \AddToHook is defined in the latex format in current releases so somehow you have got a new etoolbox or hyperref with an old latex. How did you update?

Comment: With an current MiKTeX I can compile without errors or warnings ...

Comment: @Mensch yes you'd need an old latex to have `\AddToHook` not defined.

Comment: I'm adding the log file!

Comment: And yes... it is a old latex. I'm using an old machine :/

Comment: but an old latex would have come with compatible etoolbox and hyperref that did not use commands added years later.

Comment: Ok I added some packages via direct download in CTAN. Moved the files into the base folder and then used the terminal. Maybe I did that with hyperref or etoolbox. Is there a way to check package versions?

Comment: it's a bad idea to copy files into the standard directories, you will have over written the versions that came with the latex you are using. You are using a 2020 etoolbox with a 2015 latex, that is not going to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130884/discussion-between-jesus-isea-and-david-carlisle).