# How to indent the first line of body text in a theorem when its style is customly defined by the user?

Tags: indentation, theorems, amsthm, text, styles

I have defined a new theorem style using `amsthm` package and I have noticed that the `\parindent`I have included in the definition of the style in the line of code with comment `indentation amount` adds indentation to the **head** of the theorem instead of the body text of the theorem which is more desirable. I have noticed also that if I use the predefined default style of `amsthm` it adds indentation to the body of theorem and not to the head as I want. To make my wish clear: I want the head of the theorem with **no** indentation and the body text of the theorem **with** indentation. What I am doing wrong and how to control the indentation of the body text of the theorem in the definition of a new theorem style? Looking at the documentation of `amsthm package` I didn't find anything to help me.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheoremstyle{mythm}%⟨name⟩
{3pt}%⟨Space above⟩
{3pt}%⟨Space below⟩
{}%⟨Body font⟩
{\parindent}%⟨Indent amount)
{\bfseries\slshape}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{:}%⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{\newline}%⟨Space after theorem head⟩
{}%⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
\theoremstyle{mythm}
\newtheorem{pytha}{Theorem of Pythagoras}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}

\begin{pytha}   
Let $ABC$ right triangle with $\angle A=90^{\circ}$. Then for the sides of the triangle $AB, AC$ and $BC$ is true that:
    \begin{equation}
        (BC)^{2}=(AB)^2+(AC)^{2}
    \end{equation}
\end{pytha}

\begin{thm}(Theorem of Pythagoras)
    
    Let $ABC$ right triangle with $\angle A=90^{\circ}$. Then for the sides of the triangle $AB, AC$ and $BC$ is true that:
    \begin{equation}
        (BC)^{2}=(AB)^2+(AC)^{2}
    \end{equation}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that the default theorem isn't adding any indentation to the theorem body; you are doing it by adding the empty line after `\begin{thm}`.

Comment: @campa Do you know why the same is not happening in the new theorem style I have defined, as it includes the `\newline` command?

Comment: `\newline` starts a new line and not a new paragraph, so there is no indentation. But I fear I simply don't understand your requirements. Why hard-coding the name "Theorem of Pythagoras" in a new theorem environment? You'll probably be using it only once. And the indentation after the theorem head is very uncommon, it's like the indentation after a sectioning title. French typographic conventions?

Comment: @ campa It has nothing to do with Theorem of Pythagoras, it was just to visualize the indentation, it would be a theorem with no name at all just a number or even unnumbered. I would like to know how to control that indentation in the newtheorem style definition, and if I want it to use it (no French typographic conventions :-) ) and if I don't want to use it to make it so. Just for completeness.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447684/82917

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `changepage` package to your preamble and use the `adjustwidth` environment. Change the `<indent param>` field to suit your needs.

```tex
\begin{thm}(Theorem of Pythagoras)
\begin{adjustwidth}{<indent param>}{}
    Let $ABC$ right triangle with $\angle A=90^{\circ}$. Then for the sides of the triangle $AB, AC$ and $BC$ is true that:
    \begin{equation}
        (BC)^{2}=(AB)^2+(AC)^{2}
    \end{equation}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{thm}
```

### **EDIT**

You can create a custom environnement:

```tex
\newenvironment{indented}[1]{
    \begin{thm}[#1]\phantom\newline\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{adjustwidth}{<indent space>}{}}
    {\end{adjustwidth}\end{thm}}
```

And use it like that :

```
\begin{indented}{Pythagoras}
    Let $ABC$ right triangle with $\angle A=90^{\circ}$. Then for the sides of the triangle $AB, AC$ and $BC$ is true that:
    \begin{equation}
        (BC)^{2}=(AB)^2+(AC)^{2}
    \end{equation}
\end{indented}
```

---

**Other solution for your comment below**

```tex
\newenvironment{indented}[1]{
    \setlength\parindent{<change it to set indent amount>}
    \begin{thm}[#1]\phantom\newline\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{}\hspace{\parindent}}
    {\end{adjustwidth}\end{thm}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes it works, but I have two more questions:  
(a) What about if I want indentation only for the first line of body text? (this is for `\parindent`), and
(b) Can I achieve these without calling other packages, only working with amsthm?

Comment: For (b), I really don't know. Maybe by using `ntheorems` to declare your theorem environments. For (a), since my solution is ugly (the part to delete the empty line), deleting the `adjustwidth` environnement messes everything up. Set the parameter `<indent space>` to `0cm` and see the modification in the post above. This solution is very ugly.