# Is possible to decrease the text margin of a theorem automatically?

Tags: formatting, environments, amsthm, newtheorem

I am writing a LaTeX document where I formatting a mathstatement environment as into the following code.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \documentclass[10pt]{report} 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{layout}
    
    \usepackage{parskip} 
    \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} 
    \usepackage{fontsize} 
    \usepackage{soul} 
    \usepackage{titlesec} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage{fontspec} 
    
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{caption} 
    \usepackage{float} 
    \usepackage{hyperref} 
    
    \usepackage{enumitem} 
    \usepackage{moreenum} 
    
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    
    \usepackage{amssymb} 
    \usepackage{stmaryrd} 
    
    \usepackage{amsfonts} 
    \usepackage{mathrsfs} 
    \usepackage{yfonts}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \geometry{paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25cm}
    
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.25cm}
    
    \linespread{1.5}
    
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definizione}
    
    \newtheorem{axiom}[equation]{Assioma}
    
    \newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}
    
    \newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposizione}
    
    \newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollario}
    
    \newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Teorema}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \begin{document}
    
        \lipsum[1]
        
        \begin{theorem}[My Theorem]
            \leftskip=1cm
            \rightskip=1cm
            \normalfont
            %\setmainfont{*Actually I would like write the theorem into a particular upright font: e.g. Foothlight MT Regular, Cormorant Garamont, gfsartemisia, etc...*}
            \quad\\
            This is a Theorem formatted in my personal style.
        \end{theorem}
    
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

So to automatize the process I tried to use the commands \newtheoremstyle and \theoremstyle but I was not able to indicathe the value of \leftskip and \rightskip and I was not also able to indicate that the text must be into a new line and not into the same of the title.

So I would like if it is possibile to automatize the process: could someone help me, please?

N.B.

To follow the way I tried to use \newtheoremstyle: I point out that the text is actually into a new line but the space between the title and the text is really big!

```
\newtheoremstyle{enunciato}% The name used to refer to the new style
  {\topsep}% The vertical space above the head list, a rubber lenght (default \topsep)
  {\topsep}% The vertical space below the head list, a rubber lenght (default \topsep)
  {%A declaration of the font and other aspects of the style to use for the text in the body of the list (default \normalfont)
   \setmainfont{CormorantGaramontItalic}[
                                Path = Fonts/CormorantGaramont/ ,
                                Extension = .ttf ,
                                UprightFont = CormorantGaramond-Italic
                              ]
  }% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  { }% The extra indentation of the first line of the list, a non-rubber lenght (default is no extra indent)
  {%A declaration of the font and other aspects of the style to use for the text in the head of the list (default \normalfont)
   \setmainfont{CormorantGaramontBold}[
                                Path = Fonts/CormorantGaramont/ ,
                                Extension = .ttf ,
                                UprightFont = CormorantGaramond-Bold
                              ]}% name of head font
  { }% The text (typically punctuation) to be inserted after the head text, including any note text.
  {\newline}% The horizontal space to be inserted after the head text and "punctuation", a rubber lenght. It cannot be completely empty. As two very specital cases it can contain either a single space charactere to indicate jus a normal interword space is required or, more suprisingly, just the command \newline to indicate that a new line should be started for the body of the list.
  { }% A non-empty value for this aargument enables a complete specification of the setting of the bead itself to be supplied; an empty value means that the layout of the "plain" theorem style is used. See below for further details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

But, for your own sanity, *never* change `\setmainfont` inside a document.

Of course the theorem header and the body font should be the same as the document's. Unless you want a Frankenstein document.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% the needed changes https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67251/4427
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}
  {\trivlist}
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=\theoremmargin\rightmargin=\theoremmargin\parsep=0pt}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\theoremmargin}{1cm}

\newtheoremstyle{enunciato}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {\newline}
  {}
\theoremstyle{enunciato}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definizione}
\newtheorem{axiom}[equation]{Assioma}
\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollario}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Teorema}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}[My Theorem]
This is a Theorem formatted in my personal style.
\lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want to modify `proof` along the same line,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% the needed changes
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}
  {\trivlist}
  {\list{}{\setup@theorem}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}{\setup@theorem}%
  \item[]\textit{#1}\par\nopagebreak\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\newcommand{\setup@theorem}{%
  \leftmargin=\theoremmargin
  \rightmargin=\theoremmargin
  \parsep=0pt
  \listparindent=\parindent
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\theoremmargin}{0.5cm}
\newtheoremstyle{enunciato}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {\newline}
  {}
\theoremstyle{enunciato}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definizione}
\newtheorem{axiom}[equation]{Assioma}
\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollario}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Teorema}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}[My Theorem]
This is a Theorem formatted in my personal style.

\lipsum[3][1-2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[4][1-2]

\lipsum[5][1-2]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find it ugly, but it's your document.

Comment: Actually I was not thinking I shall to do the same for the environment \begin{proof}\end{proof}: could I implement the code you above wrote?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I added the code, with a final comment.

Comment: Thanks for edit! Answer upvoted and approved: thanks really for the help. :-)
                   
P.S.
Anyway I realise it could be stranger: but I strangerly find it helpfull and so I probably will not change this since the document I am writing it is only for me  and since I have  quasi completed it so that I actually put the question only for improve the code for next documents.

Comment: Sorry, but I observed that the proof first line of proof is inline with the title "Proof" whereas I would like it is in a new line: is it possible to do this? Finally, I tried to give the value of 0.5cm at \newcommand{\thetheoremmargin}{} and I observed that the indentation of proof title is not good. Forgive the bother.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Updated.

Comment: I saw: it seems work perfectely. Thanks really!!! :-)

Comment: Hi, forgive the bother: implementing your last code into my document the compiler signals many errors which are called with the following formula: "Too deeply nested". I tried to test it (your last code) with a short text (if you like I can put it into the question or I can share it with Mega) but nothing changed: after some pages the problem appears.

Comment: Fortunately it **seems** I was able to adjust the code: **apparently** the sequence "\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse" must be replaced with the sequence "\popQED\endlist\@endpefalse" but I would like to know your opinione about.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Yes, `\endtrivlist` should have been `\endlist`.

Comment: Perfect: thanks for the reply! :-)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the default indentation (which I set equal to 0.25cm) into proof environment vanished: I tried to reset it puting into your code the command \listparindent=\parindent which actually works but unfortunately it indents even the first line. Could I ask you how to not indent (only) the first line? Forgive the bother.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Modified the code to get indentation. I find it even uglier than before.

Comment: Oh, thanks really for the edit!!! Your **complete** code works perfectly but strangely implementing it into my code does not run: however it seems I was able to implement your new snippet code by myself into the old snippet code so that it can run into my complete code ; anyway, I think I have to advice with your version it *seems* that the body (not the first line) of the theorem environment is indented (this is really horrible, your're right about) whereas with mine not.

Comment: Into the next comment my code for those who have problems implementing that's of answer. Thanks really again,  you're very kind with me!!!  :-)

Comment: \makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@thm}
{\trivlist}
{\list{}{\leftmargin=\theoremmargin
  \rightmargin=\theoremmargin
  \parsep=0pt}
}
{}{}
\patchcmd{\@endtheorem}{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
 \pushQED{\qed}
 \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
 \list{}{\leftmargin=\theoremmargin
   \rightmargin=\theoremmargin\parsep=0pt
   \listparindent=\parindent
   }
 \item[]\textit{#1}\par\nopagebreak\noindent\ignorespaces
}{
 \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\theoremmargin}{0.5cm}