# How to write/align the text in the given format?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Theorem: **When** a quadrilateral is inscribed in a cycle i.e. the vertices of the quadrilateral lie on the 
         **circumference** of a circle; the quadrilateral is called a cyclic quadrilateral.

```
lala: xxxx lala lala
      yyyy
```

Question: How to have `yyyy` below `xxxx`?

Comment: I want the word 'circumference' just under the word 'When'

Comment: Please edit your question and do *not* add content by using comments.

Comment: I think this question has been asked already:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5526/15036

Comment: @Thruston I voted to close according to your findings.

Comment: Double post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/535815