# Theorem environment with hanging indentation, again

Tags: indentation, theorems, amsthm

I would like to have formatting of theorem environment (and only this environment) with indentation, like this

[image]

It is exactly the same question as [Theorem environment with hanging indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5526/theorem-environment-with-hanging-indentation)

The solutions from there do not want to work well in `amsart` document class which I am working with.

I have a simple solution

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\th@fancyindent{
    \itshape
    \addtolength{\leftskip}{2.5em} %indentation here
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{fancyindent}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
Text body. Text body. Text body.
\begin{thm}[Pythagoras]
    Let $a,b,c$ the sides of a rectangular triangle.
    Without loss of generality, we assume that  $a<b<c$ .
    Then, the following equality holds:
          \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{thm}
More text. And even more text.
\begin{defi}  
Everything is normal here, no indentation whatsoever. Everything is normal here, no indentation whatsoever. 
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

But it is not exactly what I am going for, since it indents the word Theorem too. How can I make my desired indented formatting starting with the Theorem on top with no indent?

Comment: Does putting `\noindent` in front of the header formatting work?

Comment: What do you mean? Where would you put it? In body of the document it does not work.

Comment: In the theorem style, before the commands to format the header. E.g., `\noindent\bfseries`?

Comment: @Davislor No, putting `\noindent` in theoremstyle does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer for future reference (because I am not an advanced LaTeX user and did not know of existence of `amsthm` package before).

This solution uses `amsthm` package and works nicely in `amsart` as well as when changing to other standard document class. It adjusts to global rules of indentation and does not break existing theorem styles.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{fancyindent}               % name of theoremstyle
{.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}           % Space above, these are standard values for AMS class document
{.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}           % Space below
{\itshape\addtolength{\leftskip}{15mm}\setlength{\parindent}{0em}}      % Body font +indent added +no indent between paragraphs
{-15mm}                                     % Indent of header amount
{\bfseries}                                 % Theorem head font
{\newline}                                  % Punctuation after theorem head and start at new line
{.5em}                                      % Space after theorem head
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}. \thmnote{[#3]}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\newtheoremstyle{fancyindentwithindents}    % name of theoremstyle
{.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}           % Space above, these are standard values for AMS class document
{.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}           % Space below
{\itshape\addtolength{\leftskip}{15mm}}     % Body font +indent added
{-15mm}                                     % Indent of header amount
{\bfseries}                                 % Theorem head font
{}                                          % Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}                                      % Space after theorem head
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}. \thmnote{[#3]}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{fancyindent}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{fancyindentwithindents}
\newtheorem{thmind}{Theorem}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
```

Now in the body of document you will produce a following outcome:
[image]

Details can be found here: http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf

Drawback is that it indeed does not work well with enumerate, to fix this one needs to follow advice here: [A theoremstyle with complete indentation using amsthm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67242/a-theoremstyle-with-complete-indentation-using-amsthm) . For instance the solution of Philippe Goutet works well with indenting enumerate

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{indentedenumerate} % name of theoremstyle
{.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}           % Space above, these are standard values for AMS class document
{.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}           % Space below
{\itshape\addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{15mm}
   \addtolength{\linewidth}{-15mm}
   \parshape 1 15mm \linewidth}             % Body font +indent added +will work well with enumerate! (you need to add makeatletter)
{-15mm}                                     % Indent of header amount
{\bfseries}                                 % Theorem head font
{}                                          % Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}                                      % Space after theorem head
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}. \thmnote{[#3]}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\makeatother
```

but in `amsart` fails to indent equations (sic!).

Answer (score 3):

A simple modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106582/4427

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\kern-2.5em\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  headindent=0pt,
  headpunct=\newline,
]{INDENTthm}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  headindent=0pt,
  headpunct={},
]{NOINDENTthm}

\declaretheorem[
  within=section,
  style=INDENTthm,
  name=Theorem
]{theorem}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{%
  \patchcmd\@thm
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin2.5em\itemindent-15em}}
    {}{}%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[
  style=NOINDENTthm,
  name=Definition
]{definition}

\begin{document}

Text body. Text body. Text body.
\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
    Let $a,b,c$ the sides of a rectangular triangle.
    Without loss of generality, we assume that  $a<b<c$ .
    Then, the following equality holds:
          \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{theorem}
More text. And even more text.
\begin{definition}
Everything is normal here, no indentation whatsoever. Everything is 
normal here, no indentation whatsoever. 
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: H]

Comment: It looks promising but for now I cannot avoid changes to definition environment (definitions became indented) unless I redefine it (not good).

Comment: Another quirk is that when you change documentclass from `scrartcl` to `amsart` indents in new paragraphs in a theorem appear (which I don't want to have either).

Comment: @Maria The indent after theorems is a precise choice by the AMS. I don’t see why theorems should be indented and definitions not; anyway, you can look at the linked answer for how to do it.

Comment: This comment is misleading in many ways. You can adjust indent at beginning of new paragraphs globally (inside and outside theorem enviroments uniformly) in `amsart` class by setting `\setlength{\parindent}{0em}` to whatever value you please. I was also speaking of "new paragraphs in a theorem" anyways, which is exactly why the solution you linked is worrisome: it breaks this global behavior. As noted earlier it gives rise also to other problems which is obvious after some simple modifications.

Comment: @Maria Sorry, but I can't understand what you're meaning. ***Where*** do you not want indents?

Comment: In short: the code you pasted does not answer the question - it does not produce the desired effect that I have pasted at the top of my question. This is because it changes all theorem environments. In the comments here I am just noticing some additional unexpected problems. I assumed you are better informed, therefore I was sharing them with you.

Comment: @Maria The changes were straighforward.